# Hibernate session; connected to which server? Using PostgreSQL JDBC Driver with Failover and pgpool-II

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, pgpool

The PostgreSQL documentation shows that you can pass multiple hosts in the JDBC string for use with a HA setup (bottom of page): https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

My setup has 3 nodes each with PostgreSQL server running. I have implemented HA by using pgpool-II. There is a master node and two standbys.

When I use the following hibernate property it works great:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://10.200.0.50:5432,10.200.0.51:5432,10.200.52:5432/replicationtest</property>
```

My application connects to the cluster and if say 10.200.0.50 is down it will use one of the other addresses.

But my question is this, After using:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
```

How can I check which host from the JDBC connection string my session has opened a connection with?

The code:

```
s.doWork(connection -> System.out.println(connection.getMetaData().getURL()));
```

Just gives me the original JDBC string with all three nodes.

Comment: On PostgreSQL 9.5 or newer you can set a different `cluster_name` on the master and standbys, and use `SELECT current_setting('cluster_name')`. Not sure if there's a driver-level way, try looking at the underlying `PGconnection`.

Comment: Thanks, That put me on the right track, I ended up going with `SELECT host(inet_server_addr())` . It gives the ip address of the server. The only issue in my case is that the host I connect to is pgpool which is a middle man between the client and postgresql. I have a pgpool instance on each of the three nodes and pgpool is using loadbalancing to route the queries to the three different hosts. Therefor the adress of the DB I get back might not be on the host that my session in hibernate is connected to.